# What values does "ows_q_USER_Author" collect?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-property, sharepoint-search, crawled-property

Dears,

From which SharePoint columns/fields does `ows_q_USER_Author` collect values?

It seems to be a USER (People & Group?) type of column.

Do you have any idea where the `ows_q_USER_Author` property is "located"?

I found MicroSoft description related to managed property `AuthorOWSUSER`: *The name of the user who created the page*, but I'm not really sure it works only for pages.

Regards,

Aga

Answer (score 1):

The ows_q_User_Author is a built in crawled property that mapped to managed property: AuthorOWSUSER.

It will show the user who created the item, not only for pages, but also other type of items such as documents, SharePoint sites and so on.

It’s different from Author managed property which shows the user who created the item and also the user who last modified the item.

AuthorOWSUSER managed property shows the user who only created the item.

Besides, you could use the Search Query Tool to see what values are held within the search index. For example, you could enter AuthorOWSUSER:xxx in Query Text to verify all the values that meet the text box.

Get the tool from here: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sp2013searchtool